# Add friends Facebook profile page to jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I getting a link to a friends profile page using the Facebook JavaScript API. I now am trying to add it to a `iframe` in a jQuery UI dialog. I have:

```
$('<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=505818552"><p></p></iframe>').dialog();
```

However this displays a Facebook logo with a 'go to facebook' link in the jQuery dialog. I tried using `load(url)` before `dialog()` but it didn't work because of cross-domains.

I was wondering if Facebook disables this kind of thing?

Is there a way of getting it to open in a jQuery dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not allow this. Instead, please create a Facebook App and get the user 505818552 to authorize your App.

Then you will be able to pull that user's friends list by querying

`https://graph.facebook.com/505818552/friends?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, FB disables being included in an iframe as seen in this [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xLj6Y/).

Comment: Thanks, thought so. Do you know of some other way I can do this? Is there a workaround? I want it to open in a jQuery dialog to keep in with the look and feel of the site. Thanks.

Comment: @adamjmarkham, AFAIK there's not much that could be done, otherwise what would be the point of this protection?

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway. I want to leave the question open for a while to see if anyone else has any other solution otherwise I will green tick your answer. Thanks.